# Is there a name for a function that maps a set into a subset of itself?

Tags: terminology

Say $X$ is a set of subsets of some arbitrary set. Is there a name for a function $f:X\to X$ satisfying $f(A)\subseteq A$ for all $A\in X$?

More specifically, is there a name for an $f:X\to X$ with $f(A)\subseteq A$ and $f(f(A)) = f(A)$? In decision theory, this is how choice functions behave on sets of acts, but I wonder if there is a mathematical name for these properties.

Comment: How can $f(X) \subseteq X$ possibly fail to hold?

Comment: Do you mean to say $f(A)\subseteq A$ for $A\in X$?

Comment: @DavidMitra: Do you mean $A\subset X$ instead of $A\in X$? If $f(A)\subseteq A$ for $A\subset X$, then we can say that $f$ is $A$-invariant.

Comment: Yes. I was being foolish. See edit. Note especially the _for all $A$_ part.

Comment: Your second half still confuses me.  If we're assuming $f(A) \subseteq A$, for all $A$ then we also have $f(f(A)) \subseteq f(A) \subseteq A$, and if equality holds between the two outer sets, we must have $f(A)=A$ for all $A$...

Comment: @KevinC. I don't think that's true. Proof sketch?

Comment: @Seamus: He's saying that if $f(f(A))=f(A)$, then since $f(B)\subseteq B$ for *all* $B$, then in particular we have $f(f(A))\subseteq f(A)$ (take $B=f(A)$); hence $f(f(A))\subseteq f(A)\subseteq A = f(f(A))$, giving equality.

Comment: @KevinC. $f(\{a,b\})=\{a\}, f(\{a\})= \{a\},f(\{b\})=\{b\}$. So $f(f(\{a,b\})= \{a\} \neq \{a,b\}$.

Comment: @Seamus: Your function does not satisfy $f(f(A))=A$, which is explicitly given as a condition $f$ satisfies in the second paragraph: $f(f(\{a,b\}))\neq \{a,b\}$.

Comment: @Kevin C.:  Equality of the two outer sets is not assumed!  Taking the interior on a topological space is an interesting example of a function as in the question.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin $f(f(A))$ is not supposed to be equal to $A$ but to $f(A)$.

Comment: Ah, I had misread the question as saying $f(f(A))=A$ instead of $f(f(A))=f(A)$.

Comment: @KevinC. It is supposed to hold for all $A$. Note that it says $f(f(A)) = f(A)$ NOT $f(f(A)) = A$.

Comment: Okay, that explains it.

Comment: @StefanGeschke Yes, thanks! I'd not thought of it, but things like taking the interior of a topological space will also satisfy these properties…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm stating the following definitions for function defined on the entire power set, but they make sense for any subset of the power set...)

A function $f\colon \mathcal{P}(X)\to\mathcal{P}(X)$ such that $f(A)\subseteq A$ for all $A$ is said to be *decreasing*. (If $A\subseteq f(A)$ for all $A$, we say the function is *increasing*).

If the function satisfies $A\subseteq B\Rightarrow f(A)\subseteq f(B)$ for all $A$ and $B$, then we say $f$ is *isotone*.

If the function satisfies $f(f(A)) = f(A)$, then we say the function is *idempotent*.

A function that is increasing, isotone, and idempotent is called a **closure operator**. If, in addition, 
$$f(A) = \bigcup_{B\subseteq A,\ B{\rm\ finite}} f(B)$$ for all $A$, then we say the closure operator $f$ is *algebraic*.  If $f(A\cup B) = f(A)\cup f(B)$ for all $A$ and $B$, then we say the closure operator is *topological*.

A function that is decreasing, isotone, and idempotent is called an **interior operator**. If in addition $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$ for all $A$ and $B$, then we say the interior operator $f$ is *topological*. If $$f(A) = \bigcap\limits_{B\subseteq A, B\text{ finite}} f(B)$$ for all $A$, then we say the interior operator $f$ is *algebraic*.

So it looks like you might have an interior operator; it is certainly decreasing and idempotent, but you don't say enough to tell whether it is also isotone.

You can find some of this in George Bergman's [Invitation to General Algebra and Universal Constructions](http://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/245/), Section 5.3, pages 134-139.

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect. And thanks for pointing out isotonicity (?). I think this will be an interesting extra property to explore. I have a feeling most of the interesting examples will be isotone.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a function with the properties in your question, then the function $g:A\mapsto X\setminus f(X\setminus A)$ satisfies $A\subseteq g(A)$ and $g(g(A))=g(A)$ for all $A$.  This is called a hull operator.  What you are looking for is the dual, and I am not aware of a name for this.  Maybe we should call it core-operator.  Also see my comment:  The interior operator on a topological space satisfies your conditions.